# JavaScript run same function with multiple elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, fade, fadeout

I have a JavaScript function that looks like this:

```
function buttonClick()
{
    var numberPop = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    $( "#number-add-" + numberPop ).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

I have the ability to click a button that runs this function multiple times. However, sometimes, I click it before the previous element that it affected faded out. Because of that, the fading of the previous element stops in the middle.

How can I make it so that this function can CONTINUE fading the previously affected elements WHILE fading the current element as well? This way, multiple elements can be fading at the same time.

**Edit:**

This is the entire code:

```
function buttonClick(subEvent)
{
    var numberPop = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    var mainEvent = subEvent ? subEvent : window.event;
    var div = document.getElementById('number');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="number-pop" id="number-add-'+ numberPop +'" style="z-index:99; position:absolute;margin-top:'+ (mainEvent.screenY - 98) +'px;margin-left:'+ (mainEvent.screenX - 12) +'px;">'+ '+1' +'</div>';
    $( "#number-add-" + numberPop ).stop(true, false).animate({top: "+=-200", opacity:'0'}, 3000, 'linear');
}
```

Comment: This should work; it shouldn't stop fading other elements just because you call `fadeOut` on another element. Something else is going on. Can you provide more code and, ideally, a fiddle or demo?

Comment: @EdCottrell I have added the code for my entire function.

Comment: @user2898075 looks like it might be a side-effect of using `innerHTML`. Also, there is a `1 / 1000` chance this will create multiple _ids_ with the same value

Comment: What @PaulS. said -- you are possibly overwriting the existing divs when you call this function again. Also, as he pointed out, you may end up with duplicate ids (bad).

Comment: @EdCottrell Thank you, is there an easy fix for this? Also, I am aware of the likelihood of ending up with duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell how to fix it without *all* of your code (HTML + JS) -- we can't see what the element with id "number" is. That said, it looks like you're just trying to append new HTML. So, replace this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('number');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="number-pop" id="number-add-'+ numberPop +'" style="z-index:99; position:absolute;margin-top:'+ (mainEvent.screenY - 98) +'px;margin-left:'+ (mainEvent.screenX - 12) +'px;">'+ '+1' +'</div>';
```

with this:

```
$('#number').append('<div class="number-pop" id="number-add-'+ numberPop +'" style="z-index:99; position:absolute;margin-top:'+ (mainEvent.screenY - 98) +'px;margin-left:'+ (mainEvent.screenX - 12) +'px;">'+ '+1' +'</div>');
```

That will add the new HTML without resetting existing elements.